# How to manage user session in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts-1

I am migrating java struts 1.1 application to Spring MVC. I have a question about how to handle user session, multiple users concurrently can log in and use this application.  Which is normal for any application.  Do I need to take care of anything specifically to manage user sessions just to make sure one user's activity should not be updating other user's activity/data.  I will be using the bean scopes as it is in spring mvc style.

Any suggestions on this please?

Kiran

Comment: take a look @ this link it might help https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-session-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC just like Struts are based on Servlets and need to handle user session the same way. You can access HttpSession in Spring Controller using [RequestContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) or just declare it as parameter in your controller method.

Comment: This may be more relevant to my current migration project.

Answer (score 1):

You use HandlerInterceptorAdapter and Spring Security Session management. HTTP Session management is very important. Spring already provided.

[HandlerInterceptorAdapter](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptor-example-handlerinterceptor-handlerinterceptoradapter)

[Spring Security Session management](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)